# Optional search parameter with contains method

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following SQL should demonstrate what I am trying to do.  Unfortunately, when I try to run it, I get an error saying "Null or empty full-text predicate".

```
DECLARE 
    @essaySearchTerm varchar(100), 
    @game_id varchar(100)
SET @essaySearchTerm = NULL; 
SET @game_id = 2; 

SELECT * FROM tblImageInfo i
WHERE i.game_id = @game_id 
        AND (@essaySearchTerm IS NULL OR CONTAINS(i.essay, @essaySearchTerm))
```

What does this error mean?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because SQL Server operators are not guaranteed to be short-circuited, so if you have an expression 'A OR B', sometimes both A and B will be evaluated regardless of logical value of A. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381224/sql-server-query-short-circuiting) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219397/is-sql-servers-isnull-function-lazy-short-circuited) for more details.

In your case, when @essaySearchTerm is null, it tries to evaluate `CONTAINS(i.essay, NULL)`, which is illegal. After changing your code to:

```
IF ISNULL(@essaySearchTerm, '') = ''
SET @essaySearchTerm = '""';

SELECT * FROM tblImageInfo i
WHERE i.game_id = @game_id 
  AND (@essaySearchTerm = '""' OR CONTAINS(i.essay, @essaySearchTerm))
```

the right side of the OR will be a legal expression, as `CONTAINS(x, '""')` returns an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of `@essaySearchTerm` to `""` (two double quotes) if its null or empty:

```
if @essaySearchTerm is null
set @essaySearchTerm='""';
```

Comment: Thank you, but may I ask why?